# Network Analyst for Roads, Planes, and Ferries?

Tags: network-analyst, transportation, multimodal-network

I'm trying to find out if there's a good way to test best travel routes in Alaska that involves land, sea, and air options. I've worked with Network Analyst so I know how to make and analyze a road network dataset, but I'm wondering if there's a way to include air routes and ferry routes as well??

Thinking I could fudge it a little by determining the distance and average speed of the plane and ferry options and draw that as "roads" in the network dataset. Then I'd classify them as different types of transportation.

Any other more elegant ideas?

Comment: That's the way I'd do it - I'd also look at including some restrictions for time (time of day) if possible, since plane/ferry options would run to a schedule

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way of doing this is to forming a multimodal network as explained [here.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-2-creating-a-multimodal-network-dataset.htm) All in all the lines in network are to check if the nodes are connected and finding the cost of travelling (this may not always involve finding out the fastest or least cost though). As long as you define connections and the frictions  (aka costs), the network analyst will solve that for you. You can even introduce ferry and plane schedules but this is another question and might be tricky.